# display image on my webpage from database using php

Tags: php

Below is my code. It is working correctly
but the image is not displayed on my web page. How to rectify this?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
   echo "id: " . $row["product_id"]. " - Name: " .$row["product_name"]. "                                                                       . $row["product_type"]. "Price " .$row["price"]. "photo"               .$row["product_photo"]. "<br>";
   $photo=$row["product_photo"];
   echo '.$photo.';
   echo '<img src='.$photo.'/>';
}
```

Comment: post the value of `$photo`

Comment: Provide absolute path for image in img tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below.
Make sure the full image path is coming up.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
   echo "id: " . $row["product_id"]. " - Name: " .  $row["product_name"]   . $row["product_type"]. "Price " .$row["price"]. "photo"               .$row["product_photo"]. "<br>";
   $photo=$row["product_photo"];
   echo '.$photo.';
   echo "<img src='$photo'/>";
}
?>
```